Construct strong PRP from PRP
Assume $P$ is a PRP, are the following two constructions strong PRPs.

$C^1((k_1,k_2),x) = P^{-1}(k_2, P(k_1,x))$, i.e., the composition $P^{-1}_{k_2} \circ P_{k_1}$
$C^2((k_1,k_2),x) = P(k_2, P^{-1}(k_1,x))$, i.e., the composition $P_{k_2} \circ P^{-1}_{k_1}$

